# Uniqueness (a.s.) of regular conditional distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P})$ be a probability space, $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B})$ a measurable space, and $X : \Omega \to \mathcal{X}$ a random element of $\mathcal{X}$. Also, let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$.

---

**Question.**
How unique are regular conditional distributions of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$?

---

A *regular conditional distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$* is a function $P : \Omega \times \mathcal{B} \to [0, 1]$ such that the following properties hold.

1. For all $\omega \in \Omega$, the map $B \mapsto P(\omega, B)$ from $\mathcal{B}$ into $[0, 1]$ is a probability measure on $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B})$.
2. For all $B \in \mathcal{B}$, the map $\omega \mapsto P(\omega, B)$ from $\Omega$ into $[0, 1]$ is $(\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{B}_{[0, 1]})$-measurable (where $\mathcal{B}_{[0, 1]}$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[0, 1]$).
3. For all $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and all $G \in \mathcal{G}$, we have
   $$
   \mathbf{P}(\{X \in B\} \cap G) = \int_G P(\cdot, B) \, d\mathbf{P}.
   $$

(Items 2. and 3. just say that, for each $B \in \mathcal{B}$, the random variable $P(\cdot, B)$ is a version of the conditional probability $\mathbf{P}(X \in B\mid \mathcal{G})$.)

Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are two regular conditional distributions of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$.

On the one hand, it is *not* necessarily true that $P(\omega, B) = Q(\omega, B)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$. For example, for any $\mathbf{P}$-null set $N \in \mathcal{F}$ and any probability measure $\mu$ on $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B})$, we can define $P^\prime : \Omega \times \mathcal{B} \to [0, 1]$ by
$$
P^\prime(\omega, B)
= \begin{cases}
P(\omega, B), & \text{if $\omega \notin N$,} \\
\mu(B), & \text{if $\omega \in N$.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $P^\prime$ is another regular conditional distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$, but it might hold that $P(\omega, B) \neq P^\prime(\omega, B)$ for some $\omega \in \Omega$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$.

On the other hand, suppose $B \in \mathcal{B}$ is fixed. Then we have
$$
\int_G P(\cdot, B) \, d\mathbf{P}
= \mathbf{P}(\{X \in B\} \cap G)
= \int_G Q(\cdot, B) \, d\mathbf{P}
$$
for every $G \in \mathcal{G}$.
Since $P(\cdot, B)$ and $Q(\cdot, B)$ are $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, this implies that there exists a $\mathcal{P}$-null set $N \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $P(\omega, B) = Q(\omega, B)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega \setminus N$.
However, this null set depends on $B$, so we can't *a priori* conclude that there exists a $\mathbf{P}$-null set $N^\prime \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $P(\omega, B) = Q(\omega, B)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega \setminus N^\prime$ and all $B \in \mathcal{B}$.

---

**More Precise Question.**
Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are two regular conditional distributions of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$.
Does there always exist a $\mathbf{P}$-null set $N \in \mathcal{F}$ such that
$$
P(\omega, B) = Q(\omega, B)
$$
for all $\omega \in \Omega \setminus N$ and all $B \in \mathcal{B}$?

---

I think I remember reading that this is true somewhere, but I can't find a proof. I'm fine with assuming that any measurable spaces in question are standard Borel, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true if $\mathcal{B}$ is countably generated. Specifically, 
$$
P(\omega,A)=Q(\omega,A) \quad\text{a.s.} \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
for all $A\in \mathcal{A}$ (a countable algebra that generates $\mathcal{B}$). Therefore, there exists a $\mathbf{P}$-null set $N$ s.t. $\eqref{1}$ holds for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and all $\omega\in \Omega\setminus N$. Now extrapolate this result to $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! The monotone class theorem does the trick to extend to $\mathcal{B}$